# Android M Google api client location speed always 0 and location.hasSpeed false

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, gps, location, android-6.0-marshmallow

I m using the google api client for the location updates and it is always returning the speed 0 but the location co-ordinates are coming. I have tested the app in Motorola X2. Though it works fine in other android versions.

```
LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create(); request.setPriority(Thresholds.PRIORITY_HIGH); // request.setInterval(GlobalData.GPS_INTERVAL); request.setFastestInterval(GlobalData.GPS_INTERVAL); LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, request, this)
```

---

Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: Im having the exact same issue. It took me forever to discover the problem. Try opening google maps as well as your own app and you will see positions coming with speed attached. I haven't found a solution yet. Have you?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but to whoever is still interested in a solution here is mine. Basically in every Location change I calculate the Instantaneous Speed with the following method. It is not 100% accurate due to GPS fluctuations but it's a start.Basically you need to calculate the slope of the graph, so you must take two points y1 and y2 which are two different locations in two different time points x1 and x2. The instantaneous speed derives from the formula dy/dx where dy = y2-y1 and dx = x2 -x1

```
private double calculateInstantaneousSpeed(Location location) {



    double insSpeed = 0;
    if (y1 == null && x1 <= -1) {
        //mark the location y1 at time x1
        y1 = location;
        x1 = duration.getDurationAsSeconds();


    } else {
        //mark the location y2 at time x2
        y2 = location;
        x2 = duration.getDurationAsSeconds();


        //calculate the slope of the curve (instantaneous speed)
        dy = y1.distanceTo(y2);
        dx = x2 - x1;

        insSpeed = dy / dx;

        y1 = y2;
        x1 = x2;

    }

    Singleton.getInstance().instantaneousSpeedSamples.add(insSpeed);
    //System.out.println("Instantaneous Speed m/s: "+insSpeed);
    return insSpeed;
}
```